# Difference between int *ptr = &var and int *ptr; *ptr = &var?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a code where the following works:

```
//code 1
int* p0 = &v0;
int* p1 = &v1;
.
.
.
int* pn = &vn;
```

But the following doesn't:

```
//code 2
int *p0, *p1, ...,*pn;
*p0 = &v0;
*p1 = &v1;
.
.
.
*pn = &vn;
```

Why not ? And what is the proper way to reproduce the result of code 1  while still declaring the pointers first as in code 2 ?

I need the second type because I want to convert those `*pi (i = 1 to n)`  into an array `*p[i]` and I want something like this:

```
//code 3
int *p[n];
*p[0] = &v1;
*p[1] = &v2;
.
.
.
*p[n] = &vn;
```

For some reason and for now, I don't want to convert "`vi`"s into an array.

### Edit:

Editing based on the answers that I have received:

The array method seems to be not working ! The original code that works for me is:

```
int* p0 = &v0[0];  
int *p1 = &v0[1];
... 

int* q0 = &v1[0];
int *q1 = &v2[1]; 
...
```

in the `main` I have

```
const bool cond1 = *p1 > 2; 
const bool cond2 *p2 > 3; 
...
```

etc and it works fine. So based on the answers, I tried this:

```
int* p[n], q[n],...;
int v[n][m];
```

and then

```
p[0] = &v[0][0];
p[1] = &v[0][1];
....`  


q[0] = &v[1][0];
q[1] =&v[2][0];
...
```

This code doesn't work. It returns all those boolean conditions as falls, but they are not always supposed to be so !

Comment: @user1438832 please check out the edit.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to reproduce the result of the first code sample is like this:

```
int *p0, *p1, ...,*pn;
p0 = &v0;
p1 = &v1;
.
.
.
pn = &vn;
```

Or for your array example:

```
int *p[n];
p[0] = &v1;
p[1] = &v2;
.
.
.
p[n] = &vn;
```

The asterisk in the definition designates the variable type as a pointer. In other contexts it attempts to dereference the pointer, yielding a reference to an `int`, which you cannot assign an address to without a cast.

---

You should also consider consolidating the array definition with its initialization:

```
int *p[n] = {
  &v1,
  &v2,
  .
  .
  .
  &vn
};
```

Comment: Thanks and what about the third kind ? Can you please add that array part to your answer ?

Comment: the array method doesn't work ! The code that works is: I had `int* p0 = &v0[0];  int *p1 = &v0[1]; ... ` and `int* q0 = &v1[0];  int *q1 = &v2[1]; ... ` in the `main` I have `const bool cond1 = *p1 > 2; const bool cond2 *p2 > 3 ...` etc and it works fine. So based on your answer I tried this:  `int* p[n], q[n],... `, `int v[n][m]`, and then   `p[0] = &v[0][0], p[1] = &v[0][1],....`  and `q[0] = &v[1][0], q[1] =&v[2][0],....`   and so on. This code doesn't work. It makes all those boolean conditions falls but they are not always supposed to be !

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing two *different* uses of the `*` symbol that, in the context of what you are doing, has **two** different meanings.

First to modify the *type* of the variable to make it  *pointer type* and second to access the value that the pointer points to.

When you are *declaring* a variable the `*` belongs with the *type* (regardless where you place it).

So:

```
int* p0; // p0 is of type "int pointer"
```

Since `p0` is a *pointer type* you don't need to do anything fancy to make it point at an address:

```
p0 = &v0;
```

You only do something fancy if you want to *dereference* the pointer to get at the *value* that it points to.

```
*p0 = 5; // dereference p0 to get to the int
```

This is a *different* usage for `*`. Before it was used to provide *type* information but now it is used to *dereference* the pointer. So because it is dereferencing a variable it is semantically applied to the variable `*p0`.

So when declaring a variable as a pointer the `*` is semantically applied to the *type*:

```
int* p0; // * is part of the type
```

When accessing (dereferencing) the pointer to get its target value the `*` is applied to the variable:

```
*p0 = 5;
```

But the *language grammar* allows the placement of the `*` to go anywhere between the *type* and the *variable* in a *declaration*:

```
int *p0; // also legal but * still semantically applies to the type
```

Comment: The question is related to my this probblem: the following program:


`#include <stuff to be included>


void rmacro()
{

int* p1 = &v1;

const bool condi1 = *p1 > 0;

if(condi1){ do something}


}
`
 works but if I try : 
#include <stuff to be included>

func(int *p1)
{

const bool condi1 = *p1 > 0;

if(condi1){ do something; }
}


void rmacro()
{int *p1 = &v1;

func(*p1);


}

it shows error: Illegal pointer operation (tovalue).  I am using this as a macro in CERN's ROOT (version 5.34) shell on Ubuntu 16.04. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: @quanta `func(int* p1)` takes a pointer. You need to pass `p1` because `p1` is a pointer. But you are trying to pass `*p1` which is **not** a pointer. The `*` dereferences the pointer making it an `int`. You can't pass an `int` to a function expecting a pointer.